# idea SBT Shell window failed to init

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm use Idea Community 2017.2.1 work on Scala Programming. SBT Shell not works somehow.
Failed message output as this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=55888,suspend=n,server=y -server -Xmx1536M -XX:MaxPermSize=768M -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 -Didea.runid=2017.2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" -jar "/Users/lorancechen/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2017.2/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar" idea-shell
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=768M; support was removed in 8.0
agent library failed to init: jdwp
ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

SBT `build.properties` setting `sbt.version=0.13.16`.

Besides, SBT version setting to `1.0.2`(latest version) also not works, different with the failed message, SBT Shell window is black and not contains any information.

How to make SBT Shell works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the plugin settings in IDE. **-agentlib:jdwp=**... is specified twice in the SBT command line. This is directly stated in the error message:

> *ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.*

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java **-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket**,address=55888,suspend=n,server=y -server -Xmx1536M -XX:MaxPermSize=768M -**agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket**,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 -Didea.runid=2017.2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" -jar "/Users/lorancechen/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2017.2/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar" idea-shell

Comment: Just for a detail: check Preferences -> Build Tools -> SBT -> VM parameter, and remove `-agentlib:jdwp=...`.